How to backup and restore partition information for Ubuntu LUKS LVM backup
I have an ubuntu 20.04 system on which the boot drive is 250Gb, and current partiton size is 120Gb.
It was originally installed on a 120Gb SSD that I have now imaged onto a 250Gb SSD.
The current setup - this was originally set up by the ubuntu ?16.04? installer with the encryption option enabled. Still booting grub!!:
nvme0n1                       259:0    0 223.6G  0 disk
├─nvme0n1p1                   259:1    0   487M  0 part  /boot
├─nvme0n1p2                   259:2    0     1K  0 part
└─nvme0n1p5                   259:3    0 118.8G  0 part
  └─sdb5_crypt                253:0    0 118.8G  0 crypt
    ├─ubuntu--nvme--vg-root   253:1    0 110.8G  0 lvm   /
    └─ubuntu--nvme--vg-swap_1 253:2    0     8G  0 lvm
      └─cryptswap1            253:3    0     8G  0 crypt [SWAP]

Because I am running out of space on the drive, I am going to expand the LVM to take up the entire 223Gb soon.
Up until now I have been just unmounting the drive, booting from a live USB stick and taking a whole disk image of the drive using dd, but now I would like to improve and automate my backup situation.
Requirements

Consistent backups while mounted (no need to unmount to backup)
incremental backups (daily/weekly/monthly snapshots)
preserves all permissions and ownership of all files
mountable backups to recover individual files
preferably compressed
encrypted (although I could easily mount a luks container/volume and use that as a backup destination)

Because I don't want to store the empty space on the drive, I believe I need to use a filesystem-level backup, but I'm unsure how best to recreate the boot partition and LVM setup if I do use a filesystem backup.
So I have been looking into filesystem-level backups like borgbackup and rsnapshot. I do like the idea of borgbackup because of the way it uses file chunks, so any large files like VMs that I might have will only need to store any changes, not multiple copies of the entire large file.
So my question is: if I do go with filesystem-level backups, what is the easiest way to backup and recover the entire drive setup, including boot partition, if disaster strikes and the SSD fails?
So I would need to recreate the /boot and /swap partitions, in addition to the LVM setup and then recovering the actual files, plus I believe it uses UUIDs to mount, which would be different on newly-created partitions, so I think the grub setup would need to be updated.
ie, How can I automatically backup the partition information and easily recover it to create a new bootable SSD with identical files on it?
Maybe there is a way to create an image of the drive but with an "empty" LVM partition, into which I can restore the files from borgbackup later, so recovery would be a two step process?

You would not need to back up the swap partition - you can recreate this if you need to restore the backup.    I'm also not convinced your objectives make sense to achieve with a single backup (ie incremental backups would seem somewhat at odds with a bootable backup - although I grant they are technically not mutually exclusive)

Have you considered going through the pain of building a new system "right"?   I might be inclined to use ZFS as this can tick all your boxes save that practically it needs a rebuild.

What I mean is I don't want to redo all the setup, eg setting up temp partition, etc. I'm not super confident on setting everything up, especially after a disaster. But I would like to be able to recover older versions of files on the filesystem if I want.

Another thought - your answer seems to imply you are using them, but you are not fully aware of the power of LVM's.   It IS possible to back up an LVM without turning off the system (and you can even automate it).  The trick is to create an LVM snapshot, then you can mount that and do a file level backup, then unmount and destroy snapshot.  You may need to fsck the snapshot before mounting it, but the filesystem will be in a consistent state.

I have considered setting up again, but it's like a decade of fixing problems in there!! There must be a way I can achieve backups without having to do a full disk image every time.

@davidgo I have read about LVM snapshots and considered them, but I would still need to backup the partition setup, etc and keep it bootable. That is the part that kind of scares me because the full boot process seems a lot like black magic to me, despite looking up how it works. I'm just not confident that I can get all my ducks in a row enough to set everything up properly. I also have something set up so I can boot the encrypted LVM via ssh, which is working, but also seems like black magic to me.

I'm with you about the "dark arts" of the initial boot process - but I'm fairly confident almost all of this relates to getting to grub and ensuring the "ramdisk/equivalent" initial boot image is available -and its fairly easy from that point, regardless of filesystem.  Booting a LUKS disk remotely without hackery was impossible without hacking the bootloader last I tried many years ago on Ubintu - but you can mitigate a lot of these problems with a small (20 gig or so) root+boot and an encrypted LUKS partition for data.

@davidgo slightly OT now but would you mind linking to a description of the root+boot method for ssh booting into LUKS? If you mean just a usual system with a LUKS drive for data, it wouldn't suit my needs, I want the whole system encrypted at rest. I'm still using something very similar to https://stinkyparkia.wordpress.com/2014/10/14/remote-unlocking-luks-encrypted-lvm-using-dropbear-ssh-in-ubuntu-server-14-04-1-with-static-ipst/

@davidgo about the initial question, after a bit more research I think I will end up saving a backup of the MBR, an image of the /boot partition, and a borgbackup of all data on /. So recovery to a new drive would be to restore the MBR, restore the image of the /boot partition, set up the LVM and ext4 filesystem on there, fix the UUIDs in fstab then restore the borgbackup data. Maybe I'd also need to fix the UUID in the grub boot menu. I'm going to make an image of the whole drive as usual first though!!
